# Zoom to feature at Street level from World View

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, model-view-viewmodel

I am trying to zoom to feature at street level directly on click in ArcGIS Maps SDK for Dot Net (WPF).below the source code using to zoom to select feature but its taking 3 clicks to zoom to street level and also viewModel_PropertyChanged is triggering twice on single click.
Anybody has idea why its not directly zooming to street level

```
   async void viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
 
 
     if (isMapVisible)
     {
 
         MgdControlListView agentryVMMgdControlListView = sender as MgdControlListView;
         //Action only when the Agentry item is selected
         if (agentryVMMgdControlListView.SelectedItem != null && e.PropertyName.Equals("AgentrySelectedIndex"))
             await RecenterSelectedWorkOrder();
     }
     else
     {
         isAutoRefreshNeeded = true;
     }
 
 
}
private async Task RecenterSelectedWorkOrder()
{
         if (mapControl != null)
         {
             orderNumber = viewModel.GetAgentryString(Globals.zIsSelected);
             ApplicationViewModel vm = mapControl.DataContext as ApplicationViewModel;
             MapView mapView = ((AgentryClientControls.EsriMap.EsriMapViewController)mapControl).mapView;
             if (vm != null)
             {
                 foreach (MapPointModel Point in vm.MapPoints)
                 {
                     if (!Point.IsAggregate && Point.Detail.Contains(orderNumber))
                     {
                         //if we are here then it is a match and hence assign it as selected map point
                         vm.SelectedMapPoint = Point;
                         MapPoint featureExtent = (MapPoint)((Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Graphic)Point.GraphicIndicator).Geometry;
                         await mapView.SetViewpointAsync(new Viewpoint(featureExtent.Y,featureExtent.X,5000));
 
 
                     }
 
                 }
             }
         }
}
```